# Django DecimalField "." instead of ","

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, admin

**It seems it's a language problem with thousands separator, I think. If I use en-us in settings.py it works, but if I change it to danish 'da' it's converts it to a comma... Can I use 'da' and force a model to use english?**

If I paste or type `11.766647100448608` into the lon field in the admin and hit save, it changes the `.` to a `,` like `11,766647100448608`. The same is the case with the other field lat. Is that normal behavior, is it something on my end?

And I need the period because it is coordinates for mapbox. And my markers end up on way off on the other side of the globe.

From the model:

```
class Map(models.Model):
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='map')
lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=15, default='')
lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=15, default='')
```

From the template:

```
"type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            {{ map.lon }},
            {{ map.lat }}
          ]
        }
```

THis is what I want:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      11.766647100448608,
      55.22922803094453
    ]
  }
}
```

But this is what I get:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      11,766647100448608,
      55,22922803094453
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django admin is probably behaving correctly; the problem lies with how the decimal fields are converted to strings in the template. This is probably due to internationalization. Indeed, the [DECIMAL_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#decimal-separator) setting exists but "the locale-dictated format has higher precedence".

I suggest you try the following in the template:

```
{% load l10n %}

"type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        {{ map.lon|unlocalize }},
        {{ map.lat|unlocalize }}
      ]
    }
```

The `unlocalize` template tag is described in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/#unlocalize).